# Is it allowed to use utensils which have pictures of animals, birds or humans drawn on it?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, islamic-philosophy, image, drawing

I want to know that can I use a utensil which have pictures of animals, birds or humans drawn on it?

If it is forbidden then why?

Comment: @community: Why are you obsessed with pictures in Islam? I see that you have a moderating icon. Is it moderating to constantly return to the same petty question?

Comment: @MoziburUllah community is a bot right? or not?

Comment: @BCLC: It say's it is a bot - but I don't think it is quite.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use utensil which have pictures of animals, birds or humans drawn on it.

**It was narrated that ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) said: “I used to play with dolls in the presence of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and I had friends who would play with me. When the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) entered they would hide themselves and he would call them to come and play with me. Narrated by al-Bukhaari, no. 5779; Muslim, no. 2440.**

Also it was said

**‘Aa’ishah who said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) came back from a journey and I had hung a patterned curtain on which there were images over (the door of) a room of mine. When the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) saw it, he tore it and said, ‘The most severely punished of the people on the Day of Resurrection will be those who tried to imitate the creation of Allaah.’” She said: “So I made it into one or two cushions.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari, no. 5610; Muslim, no. 2107.**

With the above saying, we clearing understood that it is really good to avoid using it. (Though it was not directly said not to use utensil has pictures or animals, birds or humans)

Hope this helps you.